# ssl certificate for laravel app not working

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, ssl

I have developed a laravel app and deployed it to aws using s3 bucket. I want to install ssl in it. I tried to use the free ssl provided by aws with load balancer but it did not work it only showed for the homepage(not fully secure). Can someone advice me the best way to achieve this which is having the ssl ceritificate in all my pages working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use certbot.it is very much easy to use.

Just go there https://certbot.eff.org/ select your **software** & **system** & you will get the code for this.If you get any problem feel free to comment here